# Grafana - get Median of metrics

Tags: java-8, grafana

I am very new to Grafana and I am trying to get Median of some metrics.

These are the types of queries that my Team is using that I am trying to get a Median for:

`avg(backend_service_manager_className_methodName_request_time{quantile="0.75",})*1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant Documentation:

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators

```
avg(quantile(0.75, backend_service_manager_className_methodName_request_time))
```

If needed add avg for your BL, the displayed value should be pre-configured and you should not multiple by 1000.

Comment: AFAIK average and median are two different things

Comment: In fact that the explanation a bit confusing I have added `If needed add avg for your BL..` the median will not appear every time in `0.5`. after he will read the relevant documentation he will be more focused and accurate. I have fixed the way he uses the metric. Average and Median are two different things definitely.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/):

`quantile(0.5, backend_service_manager_className_methodName_request_time)` calculates the median